# Unable to process alexa intent

Tags: node.js, promise, alexa-skills-kit, alexa-sdk-nodejs

My code is not running, can anybody help.
Unable to speak out the text, can i return handler input response. The test function is a http call which may take tieme.

```
function test(url, number)
{
    return 5;
}

function speak(handlerInput) {
    return handlerInput.responseBuilder
        .getResponse();
}

const NumberFactIntentHandler = {
    canHandle(handlerInput) {
        return Alexa.getRequestType(handlerInput.requestEnvelope) === 'IntentRequest'
            && Alexa.getIntentName(handlerInput.requestEnvelope) === 'NumberFactIntent';
    },

    handle(handlerInput) {

    const theNumber = handlerInput.requestEnvelope.request.intent.slots.number.value;
    const repromptOutput = " Would you like another fact?";
    const URL = "http://numbersapi.com";

    test(URL, theNumber).then(function (data) {
             console.log("data is " + data);
             handlerInput.responseBuilder
            .speak("Test Data")
            .reprompt(repromptOutput) 

             return speak(handlerInput);
        }).catch(function (data) {

             console.log("error is " + data);
             handlerInput.responseBuilder
            .speak(`I wasn't able to find a fact for ${theNumber}` )
            .reprompt(repromptOutput)
             return speak(handlerInput);
        }); 
    }
};
```

Comment: "The test function is a http call which may take time" - How much time does the http call take. Alexa will time out after 8 seconds, so you need to be returning your response before that happens.

Comment: if you're deploying your code to AWS Lambda, I'd also suggest checking your CloudWatch logs for any errors.

Answer (score 1):

First of all your `test` function doesn't return a promise. I don't know if this is intentional and you just cut api calling code to make it simpler, but it should return a promise if you want to use `then` on it.

If it returns a promise in your full example, then what are you missing is adding a return before `test`. Also you should return `handlerInput` from inside of your promise. Code should look like this (i'll remove some of the code, that is not relevant):

```
const NumberFactIntentHandler = {
    canHandle(handlerInput) {},

    handle(handlerInput) {

    const repromptOutput = " Would you like another fact?";
    const URL = "http://numbersapi.com";

    return test(URL, theNumber).then(function (data) {
             return handlerInput.responseBuilder
                .speak("Test Data")
                .reprompt(repromptOutput) 
        }).catch(function (data) {
             return handlerInput.responseBuilder
                 .speak(`I wasn't able to find a fact for ${theNumber}` )
                 .reprompt(repromptOutput)
        }); 
    }
};
```

Now you might be wondering why do you need those `return`'s. This is because JS functions implicitly returns `undefined`, so in this case you have to explicitly tell what should be returned from `handle` function. Same applies to inside of the promise.

Comment: "Now, if you still want to use promises, you can. In your case, what are you missing is adding a return before test." - I think you should make it more obvious that this _could_ be the answer here. I think it's kind of lost in the explanation about Promises. Also, their `test` function in the code example doesn't return a Promise so `.then` isn't going to work - maybe also make it clear that that function needs to return a Promise (adding `async` would work of course).

Comment: Thanks for your feedback. I got carried away writing an answer yesterday. Looking at it with fresh eyes I see that meaning of the answer probably go lost. I updated my answer according to your remarks.

Answer (score 0):

This Code might Help You!!

```
 //use request for http call
 function fun(url) {
      return new Promise((resolve, reject) => {
       request.get(url,(err, res, body) => {
       console.log("url-fetched");
       return resolve(body);
     });
   });
  }

   const NumberFactIntentHandler = {
      canHandle(handlerInput) {..
      },

 async handle(handlerInput) {

   const theNumber =handlerInput.requestEnvelope.request.intent.slots.number.value;
   const repromptOutput = " Would you like another fact?";
   const URL = "http://numbersapi.com";
   let data = await fun(url);

   return handlerInput.responseBuilder
    .speak(data)
    .reprompt('is there any thing i can do for you?')
    .withSimpleCard('Hello', speechText)
    .getResponse();
  };
```